# GitLab CI .yml file and connection with Web server

Tags: continuous-integration, webserver, yaml, gitlab

I have set GitLab on local server with Ubuntu instalation. Also, I managed to set GitLab CI with runners and now I am struggling a bit with them. So, I have PHP project on which couple of guys are working on. We have set .gitlab-ci.yml file to deploy files on web server (which is also on same local server just under different folder).

Main problem is that GitLab CI (runner basically) deploys all files everytime and not just pushed ones.

We would like to have an option to deploy only files which are changed. 
Current yml file looks like:

```
pages:
stage: deploy
script:
mkdir -p /opt/lampp/htdocs/web/wp2/
mkdir -p .public
yes | cp -rf * .public /opt/lampp/htdocs/web/wp2/
only:
push
```

So, am I missing something huge here or there is a possibility just to deploy file which is pushed to repository? Runner is set to react on every push.

Thank you in advance for your kind replies.

cheers!

Comment: This doesn't look like a valid .yml file at all. I'm suprised this CI job actually runs.

Answer (score 2):

now, after some days and invested hours some notes did the trick...so with

```
pages:
stage: deploy
script:
- mkdir -p /opt/lampp/htdocs/web/wp2/
- mkdir -p .public
- cp -rfu * .public /opt/lampp/htdocs/web/wp2/
```

script I have managed to acheiev what I needed. "-rfu" part was the key which figures out should it replace the file if the source is newer than the destination (web server in my case).

So, this worked for me in .yml file and even that CI Lint gives the error that syntax is not correct runner gives an success. I hope that someone will find this thing useful :)